# Apache Spark Method sun.misc.Cleaner sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer.cleaner() not found during spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I am trying to run the following Spark submit from a VM using Yarn cluster mode.

```sh
./spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client test_spark_yarn.py
```

The VM has java version 11 and spark-2.4.5 while the yarn cluster java 8 and spark-2.4.0. I am getting the error below:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGmdr.png)

Comment: Please add the error message as text into your question with proper formatting instead of using a picture.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually solved by setting JAVA_HOME to jdk8. Can you please try it?